# Finding Roots of a sine function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

When we have a sine function that incorporates solo $x$'s
such as $f(x)=a\sin(2x)-bx+c$ how would I go about solving for the roots? Since I'm unable to use the basic formula for quadratic equations.

Comment: Numerical methods, there will not be closed form solutions for the zeros of $f$.

Comment: Sometimes you can solve them logically, such as when you have $f(x)=sin(x)-x$ ... Setting equal to 0 you get $sin(x)=x$, then the only possibilities are on the interval [-1,1], as that is the range of $sin(x)$. In your example, you would get $sin(2x) = (bx-c)/a$, which is still a linear function, and you would only consider possible solutions where it takes values between -1 and 1. In general, it won't have nice solutions.